# Rive(flare) files with Flutter show and works fine on QEMU Android Emulator but won't shows on a builted APK in real android device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flare, rive

Flutter Doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.14.7-pre.24, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.18363.592], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including the following components:
        MSBuild
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

I have two flare objects explicity declared on pubspec.yalm :

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/ericodigosSplash.gif
    - assets/ic_launcher.png
    - assets/flares/interruptorCircadiano.flr
    - assets/flares/space_vaporwave.flr
```

I'm already tried `flare_flutter: ^2.0.1` and `smart_flare` dependences, neither works on a builted apk.

I test on two diferent android devices. The flr (rive) files shows up just on emulator.

https://github.com/ericodex/ericodigos

Comment: I already try flutter clear, and build another project and use de same code.

Answer (score 0):

Before run `flutter build apk` run: `flutter build bundle` and it's works!